# how to convert xml result into array

Tags: php, xml, json, codeigniter

```
<entry>
    <string>actiontypedesc</string>
    <string>Registration of google1231.com for 1 year</string>
</entry>
<entry>
    <string>unutilisedsellingamount</string>
    <string>-1531.770</string>
</entry>
<entry>
    <string>sellingamount</string>
    <string>-1531.770</string>
</entry>
<entry>
    <string>entityid</string>
    <string>57928339</string>
</entry>
<entry>
    <string>actionstatus</string>
    <string>Success</string>
</entry>`
```

this is the output after the API call how do i convert it into the array?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Or should we just do your entire work? (Which we won't)

Comment: $xml = simplexml_load_string($store_array);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($array);

Comment: Then edit your question and show what you have tried so we see that you have tried something!

Comment: I'll recommend you read about it : [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

Comment: An array of what? XML array? JSON array? JavaScript object array? .NET object array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can try using [**simplexml_load_string()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php). Enclose your whole xml by a parent tag. Here I included `<myxml>...</myxml>`. Example:

```
$myXMLData =
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<myxml>
<entry>
    <string>actiontypedesc</string>
    <string>Registration of google1231.com for 1 year</string>
</entry>
<entry>
    <string>unutilisedsellingamount</string>
    <string>-1531.770</string>
</entry>
<entry>
    <string>sellingamount</string>
    <string>-1531.770</string>
</entry>
<entry>
    <string>entityid</string>
    <string>57928339</string>
</entry>
<entry>
    <string>actionstatus</string>
    <string>Success</string>
</entry>
</myxml>";

$xml = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($myXMLData)), true);
// json_encode() & json_decode() is to convert object to array
print '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
print '</pre>';
```